# How to perform login authentication and authorisation for oracle restful web services?

Tags: android, json, rest, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am using oracle restful web services from oracle apex to fetch data from oracle database . I know how to fetch data using oracle web service but I cannot figure out how to send username and password to authenticate a user that existed in oracle user roles.

I am aware of the fact that there are two ways i.e first party authentication that takes session id and app id as a parameter .But I want to send username and password just like a normal login scenario.
Please help me in this regards.

Comment: I didn't found any solution since 2 days

Comment: I am also trying to get this to work by passing a base64 encoded Basic Authorization header in my requests, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking into this myself over the last few days as I just wanted to authorize using basic style authentication (username:password) but it seems like its not supported. According to the Oracle documentation, you are limited to First Party (session id/app id) and OAuth.

> **RESTful Services support two kinds of authentication:**
>
> First Party Authentication. This is authentication intended to be used
>   by the party who created the RESTful Service, enabling an APEX
>   application to easily consume a protected RESTful Service. The
>   application must be located with the RESTful Service, i.e. it must be
>   located in the same Oracle Application Express workspace. The
>   application must use the standard Oracle Application Express
>   authentication.
>
> Third Party Authentication. This is authentication intended to be used
>   by third party applications not related to the party who created the
>   RESTful Service. Third party authentication relies on the OAuth 2.0
>   protocol.

Comment: so method you followed to achieve your target ? i  am thinking to make a table of users in which i have usernames and pwd of all user . i will make rest request from client send username and pwd to oracle apex ..in return i get session id which i would use all way along in my app :D

Comment: I'm using the OAuth method, but it sounds like my use case is pretty different to yours.